# Automatic percentage calculator

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on a code to calculate percentage but I need it to calculate the percentage automatically without the submit button, that is I want it to output the calculated percentage without the need of the user hitting the submit button.

Here is my code

```
Input: <input type="text" id="input"/><br />
Percent: <input type="text" id="percent" value="50"/>%<br />
Output: <input type="text" id="output"/>


function calc() {
  var i = document.getElementById("input").value;
  var p = document.getElementById("percent").value;
  var o = (i/100) * p;
  document.getElementById("output").value = o;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On each of the two inputs, add `onchange="calc();"` (updates when user tabs to the next field) or `onkeyup="calc();"` (updates whenever user types something).